# Surface integral of a complex Log function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, continuity, contour-integration, surface-integrals

I am trying to calculate the surface integral of a complex Log function i.e.
$$ \int\int_{|z|<1}{Log(x+i y-(x_0+iy_0)))dxdy}$$
where $z=x+iy$ and $x_0,y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ .
I know that for analytic functions it is possible to calculate it like this
$$ \int\int_{|z|<R} f(z)dxdy=\pi R^2f(0)$$
But I'm not sure how Log's singular point will affect the solution.

In addition, the Log function has a jump when completing a rotation which means it is not continuous, is this integral well defined?

Thanks in advance!